# How to get burried "nodeContent" in an array

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

HI all, I have spent a couple hours on SO trying to get this solved. Long story short I am trying to get the value from a nodeContent in an array. When I have a breakpoint and "print description" of an array this is what its spits out. My question is, how do I get the content of the burried "nodeContent" listed below? I would like to get this back in a string if possible?

NSArray Printout to console:

```
{
    nodeAttributeArray =     (
                {
            attributeName = class;
            nodeContent = g;
        }
    );
    nodeChildArray =     (
                {
            nodeAttributeArray =             (
                                {
                    attributeName = href;
                    nodeContent = "/site.aspx?s=23RBHJz4%2bck%3";
                }
            );
            nodeChildArray =             (
                                {
                    nodeContent = update;
                    nodeName = div;
                }
            );
            nodeContent = "3.49"; //THIS IS THE VALUE I WANT
            nodeName = a;
        }
    );
    nodeContent = "";
    nodeName = th;
}
```

Can I get it back as a string ?

```
NSString * value = [code]??
```

I would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify `TFHppleElement` to return the children objects.

in `TFHppleElement.h`:

```
@interface TFHppleElement : NSObject
[..]

- (NSArray*)children
@end
```

in `TFHppleElement.m`:

```
NSString * const TFHppleNodeChildArrayKey     = @"nodeChildArray";

@implementation TFHppleElement
[..]
- (NSArray*)children {
    [node objectForKey:TFHppleNodeChildArrayKey];
}
[..]
@end
```

So now you can get it like this,

```
NSString *value = [[[object children] objectAtIndex:0] content];
```

**Original Answer**

The printout suggests that it is a dictionary object based on the curly braces. You might want to look at [`this`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html). For this case, you should be able to get your value using,

```
NSString *value = [[object valueForKeyPath:@"nodeChildArray.nodeContent"] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Hey Deepak, thanks for the reply. I tried your suggestion but I am getting an exception when hitting the line. Any other suggestions by chance? Thanks man!

2011-06-05 09:51:35.198 Hpple[12055:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<TFHppleElement 0x4e21dc0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key nodeChildArray.'

Comment: You should be messaging `node` rather than the `TFHppleElement` instance.

Comment: Im not entirely sure how to do that? Ill search around a bit!

Comment: Actually, now that I understand what your actual problem is. I suggestion you modify `TFHppleElement` class to have a `children` method that returns the array pointed by `nodeChildArray`. Probably that's a better approach.

Comment: @Louie modified the answer with the suggested modifications.

Comment: Hey Deepak, im trying to setup your suggestion. Ill keep you posted.

Comment: Many hours later! ... I got it... thanks to your suggestions. thumbs up!